# asp.net mvc и ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Подскажите как реализовать в asp.net mvc приложении property injection следующим образом:

Во всех примерах в основном показано инжектирование путем внедрения зависимости через контроллер. В моей задаче внедрение зависимости надо реализовать не в контроллере а в обычном классе, дело в том, что я хотел реализовать некий класс-контекст, который будет содержать свойства на все репозитории в приложении. И затем использовать в контроллере экземпляр этого класса.

В моем случае я создал такой класс, но при первом обращении к свойству класса(которое имеет вот такой тип к примеру: IRepository) мне выдает ошибку на этапе выполнения что это свойство равно null, то есть оно не инициализируется. Как грамотно можно реализовать такой класс, подскажите пожалуйста, а то я еще не сильно понимаю в DI? Немного кода. К примеру, мне нужен вот такой класс:

```
public class UoWManager
{
    [Inject]
    public IRepository<Car> GetCarsrepository { get; set; }

}
```

Затем я создаю обертку (резолвер):

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver:IDependencyResolver
{
    private IKernel kernel;

    public NinjectDependencyResolver()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
    }

    private void AddBindings()
    {
        kernel.Bind<IRepository<Car>>().To<SQLCarsRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<UoWManager>().ToSelf();
}
```

Регистрирую его в Global.asax:

```
 DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver());
```

И затем использую мой класс - контекст в контроллере:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{    
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        UoWManager man=new UoWManager();

        Car Temp = new Car();
        Temp.Mark_car = "1";
        Temp.Model_car = "2";
        Temp.Price_car = 233234;
        Temp.Type_car = "Truck";
        Temp.Year_of_issue_car = DateTime.Now.Year;
        man.GetCarsrepository.Create(Temp);

        return View();
    }

}
```

Вот при таком раскладе мое свойство `GetCarsRepository` не инициализируется. А если к примеру его объявить прямо в контроллере то все в порядке.

Собственно вопрос - как правильно свзать мой класс UoWManager с нинжектом?

Answer (score 2):

NInject и DependencyResolver никаким хитрым образом в процесс создания объектов не вмешиваются. При создании через `new` вы получаете обычный экземпляр с неинициализированными полями.

Для инициализации полей `UoWManager` вы должны получить его экземпляр через DependencyResolver, а не просто создать через `new`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var man = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<UoWManager>();

    //...
}
```

Но т.к. ваш контроллер, по сути, зависит от `UoWManager`, то правильнее было бы оформить эту зависимость явно. Экземпляр контроллера создается через DependencyResolver, и все его зависимости будут заполнены к моменту вызова Action:

```
[Inject]
public UoWManager UoWManager { get; set; }

public ActionResult Index()
{
    IRepository<Car> repository = this.UoWManager.GetCarsrepository;

    //...

    return View();
}
```